# Spark: Is there way to find number of records in a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a directory structure in HDFS as follows:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/2011/01/01/*
/dir1/dir2/dir3/2011/01/02/*
..
```

I have done the following to read all the files at lest I assume by doing following it will read all the files:

```
val data = sc.textFile("/dir1/dir2/dir3/2011/**/**")
```

I want to make sure I have read all data under 2011 (all months and dates), I thought one by checking the size of the RDD would give me an idea.

Answer (score 2):

That would be `count` - [docs here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions).

Comment: Funny how many times you can peruse the API and still miss what you're looking for. The confusion for me was between the terms *records* and *elements*, which I now realize refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to point to each file under each directory. Instead, it is enough to point just to the `2011` folder, like this: `/dir1/dir2/dir3/2011/*`.

By the way, I think you might be mixing some concepts here. The records inside a RDD do not represent the file quantity on the HDFS directory you point to. Each RDD is a set of records, wich are split in partitions of part or all of a **single file**.

In a distributed application, you can have a big amount of different RDD-s, one for each file. So, getting the records of a RDD directly on code, it will give you the amount of *rows* available in that precise partition of the RDD.

Comment: if I do what you mention and do `data.take(2)` I get `java.io.IOException: Not a file dir1/dir2/dir3/2011/01/01`

Comment: Have you check that `dir1/dir2/dir3/2011/01/01` actually exists and it is a file?